# using for loop inside an array in Swift3

Tags: arrays, for-loop, swift3

I'm trying to get an array called pages has 604 elements which are from 1 to 604 integers.

My code right now is:

```
class Myclass{
    for x in 0..<604 { var pages[] = [i] }}
```

the error message is:

> Expected declaration

any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For loop in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129578/for-loop-in-swift)

Comment: @Dai I tried that before but it didn't work with me.

Comment: Please post more of your code in-context. What happens if you strip your source-file down to the bare minimum? If it still happens, please post it here.

Comment: Also is your Swift compiler set to use Swift 3 syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you never intend mutate `pages` beyond initialization, you can simply initialize an immutable array with the sequential integers:

```
class Myclass {
    let pages = Array(1...604) // [1, ..., 604]
     /* ^^^^^ type inferred to 'Array<Int>' */  
}
```

The array initialization above makes use of the [by `Sequence` initializer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1538750-init) of `Array`

> ```
> init<S : Sequence where S.Iterator.Element == Element>(_ s: S)
> ```